# Kotlin: EditText must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

tengo un problema con un EditText del cual no puedo obtener su valor. En el mainActivity instancio un DialogFragment personalizado, el cual tiene una EditText del cual quiero extraer su valor y validarlo, pero al dar clic sobre el boton "Guardar" me arroja un error: EditText must not be null.

Este es el codigo que manda llamar el DialogFragment:

```
val dialogList = DialogNewList()
dialogList.show(supportFragmentManager,"newlist")
```

y este es el codigo donde se procesa la parte de obtener el valor del EditText en el dialogo:

```
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
                    val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater;
                    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_dialog_new_list,null))
                        .setTitle("Nombre de nueva lista")
                        .setPositiveButton("Guardar",
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                                val nuevoNombre = etName.text.toString()
                                if(nuevoNombre != ""){
                                    listQueryDB.setNewList(nuevoNombre)
                                    etName.text.clear()
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(BaseDB.CONTEXT,"Necesitas escribir un nombre a la lista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                            })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar",DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                            getDialog()?.cancel()
                        })
                    builder.create()
                } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}
```

el error aparece cuando se intenta ejecutar la linea:

```
val nuevoNombre = etName.text.toString()
```

y el error que muestra el Logcat es el siguiente:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: etName must not be null
```

El ID del EditText (etName) es correcto incluso Android Studio lo reconoce porque me muestra las sugerencias de código mientras escribo después de poner el nombre del ID. ¿Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal, o qué me falta por hacer para poder obtener el valor del EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu editText no se inicia por defecto aunque tenga el mismo nombre que el id de tu layout, debes inicializarlo cuando obtengas tu view con el layoutInflater

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_dialog_new_list,null)
etName=view.findViewById(R.id.etName)
builder.setView(view)
```

Comment: Gracias danms07 lo unico que cambie fue:

`val nuevoNombre = view.etName.text.toString()`

Ya que con Kotlin no necesito el findView

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn pero, la pregunta esta realizada en Kotlin, revisar [answer], saludos